# The length of first tab persists to be active

Tags: css, z-index

My first tab longer than second one. In first tab there are links and images with anchor link.The problem is first tab's links are still active although I click on second tab and lays down on my tag cloud, so prevent them to be clickable. I would like to know why links of first tab are still clickable althoug they are not appearing?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/y6t7mxcx/)

HTML

```
<section class="tabs">
            <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">About</label>

            <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
            <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">Services</label>

            <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-3" />
            <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">Work</label>


            <div class="clear-shadow"></div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="content-1">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-thumb thumbnail" rel="bookmark" title="testing editor styles">
        <img src="#"  width="250" height="250"/></a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-thumb thumbnail" rel="bookmark" title="testing editor styles">
        <img src="#" width="250" height="250"/></a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-thumb thumbnail" rel="bookmark" title="testing editor styles">
        <img src="#" width="250" height="250"/></a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-thumb thumbnail" rel="bookmark" title="testing editor styles">
        <img src="#" width="250" height="250"/></a>

                </div>
                <div class="content-2">
                    <h2>Most Commented</h2>



                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
  <a href="">Link</a>
```

CSS

```
    .tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs input#tab-2{
    left: 100px;
}
.tabs input#tab-3{
    left: 220px;
}
.tabs input#tab-4{
    left: 340px;
}

.tabs label {
    background: #5ba4a4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%, #4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5ba4a4), color-stop(100%,#4e8c8a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 12px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    color: #385c5b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.tabs label:after {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
}

.tabs input:hover + label {
    background: #5ba4a4;
}

.tabs label:first-of-type {
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.tab-label-2 {
    z-index: 3;
}

.tab-label-3 {
    z-index: 2;
}


.tabs input:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 6;
}

.clear-shadow {
    clear: both;
}

.tab-content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 5;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;

}

.tab-content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;


    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}

.tab-content div img { border: 1px solid #903; position: relative;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .tab-content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .tab-content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .tab-content .content-3 {
    z-index: 100;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
  transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
  position:relative;
}
.tab-content div h2,
.tab-content div h3{
    color: #398080;
}
.tab-content div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    border-left: 8px solid rgba(63,148,148, 0.1);
}
.tab-content li {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0 0 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `opacity:0` does make your div transparent but it is still there. Change `opacity:0` to `display:none` insteed

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzz8r6cc/)**

Comment: There are a lot of opacity, I could not realize which one I should change

Comment: if You want to learn front end you should start using "inspect element" right clicking in your browser. Its your best friend tool. You should add display:none to .tab-content div (removing display:flex), and on check rule, display:flex insteed of opacity:1. https://jsfiddle.net/gzz8r6cc/

Comment: However, and it's just my litlle opinion, not meaning any offense, the code you wrote is quite a mess and full of "tricks". Not very clean. Unless is a "all css" school project or similar, what you are trying to achieve can be done, easier and more clean with simpler css and just a bit of jquery,

Comment: I have some basic understanding of using CSS but these things little bit tricky, how could I improve my CSS, do you have some tips pleaese?

Comment: If tomorrow I have time, it's bed time right now  here, I will try to give you an example... Not "hiding" radio buttoms so you can call them with css but doing it clean with easy jquery on on click functions.  Can't promise I'll have the time.

Comment: And if these CSS are written by you, you don't have "basic" understanding, but I guess someone else wrote it. As I said, your example css are complex and full of "tricks" (to avoid javascript I guess). We will see tomorrow (if I have the time). nn